# Why do I have the teacher badge even though haven't answered any questions?

Tags: support

I just joined gamedev to ask one question that seemed too game-dev for StackOverflow, and noticed that I have the `teacher` badge even though I've only just joined haven't answered any questions.

[image]

Then when I [clicked the badge, I ended up here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/badges/1/teacher?userid=41753) which tells me I've earned it for this answer on [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/11712/internal-game-organization/11714#11714):

[image]

Which I'm not only 99% sure wasn't written by me, but also couldn't have been posted by me because I only joined today ([see here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/41753/marty)).

What's happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That question was asked on stackoverflow, where you apparently answered it. It was then migrated here, then you were awarded the badge, then it was closed. Then it appears the answers it had were removed by community, which is why your answer is currently deleted.

Comment: Ah, makes sense though it's somewhat convoluted. I probably wrote like that 3 years ago as well.